# `alldifferent` method in MiniZinc

Tags: minizinc

The following is the constraint I tried to implement in MiniZinc

`constraint forall (t in trucks)
(all_different(c in customers where sequence[t,c] !=0) (sequence[t,c]));`

that is, I want every row element to be different for the `sequence` matrix when the `sequence` value doesn't equal to 0.

and got the error

`MiniZinc: type error: no function or predicate with this signature found: all_different(array[int] of var opt int)'`.

As indicated by some other threads I've added `include "alldifferent.mzn";` command, still showing that error.

This is part of assignment, sorry for not able to push all my code here, please let me know if there is any extra information needed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To clearly understand what you are doing, you can write your expression in a different way:

```
all_different([sequence[t,c] | c in customers where sequence[c,t] != 0])
```

Note that this uses array comprehensions. These are great to express a lot of things, but if `sequence` is an array of variables then the **number of variables** in this comprehension is **unknown**. This is a big problem for many solvers. And is thus not supported by many of them.
*It is at least impossible with the `all_different` predicate.*

Your problem however is a well known one, thus a different predicate is available. You can express the same constraint in the following way:

```
for(t in trucks) (
    alldifferent_except_0([sequence[c,t] | c in customers])
)
```